# Set current list item as selected in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items; the number of items in the list is different each time:

> ```
> <li id='item1'>number_1<li>
> <li id='item2'>number_2<li>
> …
> <li id='itemn'>number_n<li>
> ```

When a user choose an item. I want to set the item as selected. 
In my code. I can get the id of each item. my problem is I cannot set the item as selected; for example. if I get item2. I want to the item become as

> ```
> <li id='item2' class="selected" >number_2<li>
> ```
>
> Since the id is a variable in mycode. I tried lots of ways to do that in my jquery script. like:
>
> ```
> $("#id").addClass('selected'); // doesn't work;
> $("li" id).addClass('selected'); // doesn't work;
> $("#" id).addClass('selected'); // doesn't work;
> $($this. id).addClass('selected'); // doesn't work;
> ```

I searched on the web, maybe this is too simple probem, I didn't find similar questions and answers. Can anybody please help me out. thank you!

Comment: How about a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `#` to your ID like this:

```
$("#" + id).addClass('selected');
```

Your code should look something like this (no need to store the ID in a variable as you mentioned):

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: I think you have an extra space in `$('li .selected')`; also, I would just change that to `$(this).addClass(...).siblings().removeClass(...)`.

Comment: The `$('li.selected')` is still looking at the whole DOM and really seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
$('#'+id).addClass('selected');
// or
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

it depends on where you're trying to execute this code, though.

Comment: you are the best! $('#'+id).addClass('selected'); this works!!!Thank you very much!

Comment: If your problem is solved then you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that was most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside the click handler when you're trying to set this, the easiest is:

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

If you have the variable `id`, but are not inside the click handler, you want:

```
$('#'+id).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id").addClass('selected'); // doesn't work;
```

this should work, import your jquery before You use this code.